# Retrieving data from two tables first table text data second table media images. the images fails

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys i have two tables one contains the property info and second is images of

property. i want to Retrieve the images of property from second table by selecting the

first table one row but it fails. it just display the info of property NOT images.

any one please?

```
  <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    require_once('db.php');
    if(isset($_POST['property']))
    {
        $property=$_POST['property'];
        $propertyquery = "SELECT PropertyImageID, PropertyName, PropertyStatus FROM properties WHERE PropertyImageID =$property ";
        $propertyquery_run= mysql_query($propertyquery);
       if (mysql_num_rows($propertyquery_run) > 0) 
          {
        while ($propertyrow = mysql_fetch_array($propertyquery_run)) 
          {?>
            <div>PropertyName: <?php echo $propertyrow['PropertyName']   ?>  </div>
            <div>PropertyStatus: <?php echo $propertyrow['PropertyStatus'] ?>  </div>


    <?php }

        $imagequery ="SELECT PropertyImageID, ImagePath FROM propertyimages WHERE PropertyImageID='".$propertyrow['PropertyImageID']."'";
         $imagequery_run=mysql_query($imagequery);
                if(mysql_num_rows($imagequery_run) > 0)  
                {
                    while ($imagerow = mysql_fetch_array($imagequery_run))  
                    {
                    ?>
                       <div style="border:solid 2px #9F0; border-radius:5px; height:222px; width:544px;">
                       <img src="<?php echo $imagerow['ImagePath'];  ?>" >
                       </div><br />    
                    <?php
                    }

                }
            }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Go Back And Set Your Session.Thanks';
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysql never writes query on its own, you need to use `JOIN` to achieve this..

Comment: not working i used JOIN, InnerJoin, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN But not result??????????????

Comment: show the code where you used that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your this lines

```
$imagequery ="SELECT PropertyImageID, ImagePath FROM propertyimages WHERE PropertyImageID='".$propertyrow['PropertyImageID']."'";                                           
$imagequery_run=mysql_query($imagequery);
```

should be in while loop right now they are out of while loop.

Comment: 'Your this lines

$imagequery ="SELECT PropertyImageID, ImagePath FROM propertyimages WHERE PropertyImageID='".$propertyrow['PropertyImageID']."'";                                           
$imagequery_run=mysql_query($imagequery);

should be in while loop right now they are out of while loop.
' sorry its not belonging to the first query?????????????

Comment: Yes u are trying to use while loop value $propertyrow but you are closing your while loop before executing your query inside it

Comment: ya one extra } was there now working thanks alot.

Comment: ya its working perfectly